# Is it okay to keep Windows 7 for gaming only?

Tags: windows, windows-7

I have some games which work on Windows only, but I don't want to buy a new Windows, I would rather keep Windows 7 as a second OS for gaming and use Linux or BSD for working, browsing, etc. As far as I know vulnerabilities in multiplayer game clients are very rare, so there is only a very low chance that somebody hacks the system while I am gaming. Some people argue that it is a massive security risk that I keep an EOL OS even though I would not use it for browsing, just for playing the old games I downloaded from safe official sources. I don't agree, because I don't think such a system has a big attack surface, but I am curious what do experts say?

update based on the comments

Looks like game clients are not safe at all:
https://www.networkworld.com/article/2166509/researchers-find-critical-vulnerabilities-in-popular-game-engines.html

Still this is not a Windows 7 related issue, I guess Windows 10 can be hacked through these game vulnerabilities too. So the question remains, for this specific game only usage does Windows 10 give any security advantage over Windows 7 and if so what?

Comment: Is this a dual boot setup ? If it is the case my worry would be that a compromised Windows contaminates the Linux partitions or destroys all data on the disk (ransomware). The simple solution is to run Windows in a virtual machine but since you mentioned gaming that may not be a solution if you need performance and responsiveness. It depends on what software you use.

Comment: *"...I don't want to buy a new Windows..."* - it is still possible to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 with no cost (no hack, nothing illegal). There are lots of information about this on the internet. *"As far as I know vulnerabilities in multiplayer game clients are very rare..."* - what is this knowledge based on? [This search](https://www.google.com/search?q=critical+security+bugs+in+multiplayer+games) suggests otherwise.

Comment: @Anonymous The question is about whether there is a real risk that the system will be compromised with this specific usage. Yes, it is dual boot. I don't think data loss is an issue, it is more like a workstation and most of the data is stored on a local server. Not to mention that I cannot read typical Unix filesystems from Windows and even if I could I can easily encrypt them if I want to.

Comment: A malmware could still wipe your disk even it it cannot decrypt your Linux partitions. It could also reach your local server and maybe erase your backups. While no system is 100% safe running an EOL OS, whatever it is, increases the risk significantly. If your games do not require Internet access you could unplug the cable or disable networking completely.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I read it many years ago, but it is just simple logic. Game clients are lot simpler than browsers and they use very specific data formats which is easy to validate. Image viewers are rarely hacked for the same reason.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich https://www.networkworld.com/article/2166509/researchers-find-critical-vulnerabilities-in-popular-game-engines.html I found meanwhile a few interesting articles with your search. But as far as I understand even with Windows 10 this would be an issue, so this is not Windows 7 related. Still it is interesting. Maybe a newer OS would complain that it is being hacker or an antivirus would notice it. I am not sure if I should expect such targeted or semi-targeted attacks.

Comment: @inf3rno: *"Image viewers are rarely hacked for the same reason."* - nice comparison. Image, video and other codec libraries are notoriously known to be often buggy since they are optimized for speed and don't assume bad input.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich So what is the conclusion regarding to the question? :D

Comment: @Anonymous Wiping the Unix partition is not a big deal. It would contain the keys necessary to access the server, so I would be happy if a compromised computer would do that. At least I would know there is an issue with it and wipe it totally.

Comment: @inf3rno: First it is still possible to upgrade to Windows 10 for free as I already said. If this is not possible (maybe some games will not play) the risk is probably manageable  (i.e. risk is not zero but impact is low) if you encrypt the disk of your Linux system as you proposed and if there are no potentially vulnerable devices (like a router or printer) in the network which could be hacked when somebody managed to hack your Windows system.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Ok, I'll check this free upgrade stuff. I thought the free upgrade period was over years ago. Good point, I just bought a printer, but it will be connected to the server via USB and I will be able to access it through CUPS / IPP everywhere, not directly. I am not sure about the router. Are there vulnerable routers?

Comment: @inf3rno: "Are there vulnerable routers?"* - vulnerable routers are about as common as vulnerable image/video/codec libraries, or even more common.

Comment: @inf3rno not only upgrades, Microsoft distributes the Windows 10 installation media and lets you install for free. https://www.howtogeek.com/244678/you-dont-need-a-product-key-to-install-and-use-windows-10/

Comment: @multithr3at3d Is it possible that way to use my win7 key for activation?

Comment: @inf3rno I don't think so, but activation is technically not required

Comment: @multithr3at3d I am not sure the restrictions stops by changing background picture. I have 2 screens atm one of them is 144Hz with adaptive sync, if I cannot set the frequency properly that would be an issue. I'll try it out, thanks. I'd rather go with this than with the win7 upgrade.

Comment: @inf3rno I was in the exact same situation as you, from a technical perspective. I'd recommend just upgrading. Windows 7 will only become more and more broken, and you'll be just like the people who cling to Windows XP today. I *highly* recommend you just biting into the sour apple and getting yourself a Windows 10 license. They cost 139 USD, and while that's not *cheap*, it's not something impossible to afford either. And if you do some googling, there's *still* ways to upgrade Windows 7 to Windows 10 for free. As it stands, there is **no reason** to stay on Windows 7.

Comment: @inf3rno I would mostly worry about MMO launchers - many old ones use IE as a component. That said, a few years back there was an EU ruling that required MS to allow reselling Win10 licenses - I bought mine for roughly 10 euros. It activated and I'm getting updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a general perspective it is safe enough.

I know that many times you will have to run an old OS due to compatibility issues with software, in your case - games. I still practically use XP due to that in some scenarios and I do that in a very safe manner.

In your case things may be easier than average: on the online gaming part you can allow only the ports used by the gaming services/servers and you can secure everything else. You may even close-up browsing-related capabilities completely or block most of the TCP ports with very few exceptions.

In this one should not take game vulnerabilities into account since those are not breaches of the OS, but of the games. On the OS part you should be pretty good overall for many years ahead.

In the specific situation of Windows 7, things are looking good. There are still 2 more years of actual support of it (see the MS descriptions about this) and by the end of this period Windows 7 will already have a low enough coverage not to be a primary target of exploiting anymore.

Even if universal exploits are found (that are cross-versions and affecting any Windows OS) most of them will still be able to be community patched.

So I would not worry. Gaming on Windows 7 will still be good for years and the obvious choice of old enough games. Even if groups like GOG try to make most games work with Windows 10, older ones will work better on older OS'es. For a specific older game, you won't have any advantage whatsoever by using Windows 10 from a security perspective or any other.

Comment: Blocking HTTPS outbound entirely won't work - most launchers as well as GOG/Steam clients use it in one form or another. Old MMO game launchers in particular used the IE component to display content

Comment: The point is you only need a few ports.

Comment: true, but not browsing unfortunately.

Comment: On the browser side you can improve security with the actual browser by switching to an alternate more secure/more customizable one.

Comment: not really if that browser is embedded in an MMO launcher or some such.

Comment: @JanDorniak It depends on what that browser does and which servers it connects too. E.g. I think Origin connects only to specific servers (which we can assume safe) to download advertisements, etc. I am not sure what would happen if we would block certain ports or servers for origin, so it would not be able to download advertisements, but would be still good for gaming.

Comment: @Overmind Thanks, I thought the same. With very restricted internet usage it can still be ok. I have a few games I still play from the 2000s. I might install win10 too just to try it out with them. If there are no performance issues and I don't have to activate that is fine for me too.

Comment: @inf3rno depends entirely on what you play and if you trust their security. There have been situations where a notebook vendor's software update tools would install malicious payload.

Comment: For embedded browsers the biggest security concert is that embedded browser itself.